# Can you create Container Transforms (shared element transitions) on Ionic page navigation?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

What I mean with "Container Transform", is that for example when I click on a FAB, that FAB should grow and create the new page.

You can check out an example in the [official material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/motion/the-motion-system.html#container-transform), or in the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate?authuser=2#shared).

I know that this is doable with a single page, but I would really like to do this in cooperation with the router.
Is there any way to do this using a plugin, or are there any libraries that can do that?